# Applying diff on selected rows for comparing angles from math.atan2

Tags: python, pandas, diff, angle, atan2

I have a data frame like this that want to apply diff function on:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({ 'Observation' : ['0','1','2',
                         '3','4','5',
                         '6','7','8'],
                  'Value' : [30,60,170,-170,-130,-60,-30,10,20]
            })

Observation Value
0   30
1   60
2   170
3   -170
4   -130
5   -60
6   -30
7   10
8   20
```

The column 'Value' is in degrees. So, the difference between `-170` and `170` should be `20`, not `-340`. In other words, when `d2*d1 < 0`, instead of `d2-d1`, I'd like to get `360-(abs(d1)+abs(d2))`

Here's why I try. But then I don't know how to continue it without using a for loop:

```
test['Value_diff_1st_attempt'] = test['Value'].diff(1)
test['sign_temp'] = test['Value'].shift()
test['Sign'] = np.sign(test['Value']*test['sign_temp'])
```

Here's what the result should look like:

```
Observation Value Delta_Value
0   30   NAN    
1   60   30 
2   170    110
3   -170   20   
4   -130   40
5   -60    70
6   -30   30
7   10   40
8   20   10
```

Eventually I'd like to get just the magnitude of differences all in positive values. Thanks.

Update: So, the value results are derived from `math.atan2` function. The values are from `0<theta<180` or `-180<theta<0`. The problem arises when we are dealing with a change of direction from `170` (upper left corner) to `-170` (lower left corner) for example, where the change is really just `20` degrees. However, when we go from `-30` (Lower right corner) to `10` (upper right corner), the change is really `40` degrees. I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Delta_Value should not be 40 for the 7th row based on your definition?

Comment: I just added an update to my question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work (took the definition from [@JasonD's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/4472)):

```
test["Value"].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: 180 - abs(abs(x[0] - x[1]) - 180))
Out[45]: 
0      NaN
1     30.0
2    110.0
3     20.0
4     40.0
5     70.0
6     30.0
7     40.0
8     10.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

How it works:

Based on your question, the two angles a and b are between `0` and `+/-180`. For `0 < d < 180` I will write `d < 180` and for `-180 < d < 0` I will write `d < 0`. There are four possibilities:

- `a < 180`, `b < 180` -> the result is simply `|a - b|`. And since `|a - b| - 180` cannot be greater than 180, the formula will simplify to `a - b` if `a > b` and `b - a` if `b > a`.
- `a < 0`, `b < 0` - > The same logic applies here. Both negative and their absolute difference cannot be greater than 180. The result will be `|a - b|`.
- `a < 180`, `b < 0` - > a - b will be greater than 0 for sure. For the cases where `|a - b| > 180`, we should look at the other angle and this translates to `360 - |a - b|`.
- `a < 0`, `b < 180` -> again, similar to the above. If the absolute difference is greater than 180, calculate 360 - absolute difference.

For the pandas part: `rolling(n)` creates arrays of size n. For 2: (row 0, row1), (row1, row2), ... With `apply`, you apply that formula to every rolling pair where `x[0]` is the first element (a) and `x[1]` is the second element.

Comment: That works great. I figured out a way myself but it requires several lines of code. I do `test['Value_temp'] = test['Value'].apply(lambda x: 360 + x if x < 0 else x)`, then get `diff` of `Value` and `Value_temp` and finally choose the minimum! I don't need to say that your solution is way more elegant! Thanks.

Comment: Can you please describe how your solution works so that I can learn from it?

Comment: @bikhaab Sure I updated my answer. I'll try to elaborate more if anything's unclear.